# MVVM Cross Crash On ViewDidLoad

Tags: c#, ios, mvvm

On ViewDidLoad my MVVM Cross Xamarin app crash with the error below.
Xamarin IOS application that target iOS Phone and tablet (iPad).

```
at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.LoadViewModel (IMvxIosView iosView) [0x00059] in V:\Xamarin\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\iOS\iOS\Views\MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs:45 
  at MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (IMvxView view, System.Func`1 viewModelLoader) [0x00012] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (IMvxIosView iosView) [0x00001] in V:\Xamarin\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\iOS\iOS\Views\MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs:21 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxViewControllerAdapter.HandleViewDidLoadCalled (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00001] in V:\Xamarin\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\iOS\iOS\Views\MvxViewControllerAdapter.cs:28 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise (System.EventHandler eventHandler, System.Object sender) [0x00000] in V:\Xamarin\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Core\MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.cs:16 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.iOS.Views.MvxEventSourceViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00006] in V:\Xamarin\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\iOS\Views\MvxEventSourceViewController.cs:63
```

Comment: That's a nice call stack.  Too bad it doesn't include the exception type and exception message.

Comment: Null Pointer exception in LoadViewModel as per stack trace.

Comment: @Lennie: How did you solve this?